# SWIG change function signature

Tags: java, swig

I am using Swig to create a Java interface. Basically, in C++ I have template (

```
template<class T> class TSizedArray
{
    int GetLength();
    T* GetElements() const;
    ...
}

class Producer
{
    TSizedArray<long> GetLongs();
    ...
}
```

This template is used as return value of some functions of API I need to export to Java via SWIG. However, in Java we want to use native Java arrays instead of this simple wrapper:

```
Java:
    long[] result = Producer.GetLongs();
```

I am not sure how to achieve this with SWIG. The template has multiple instantiations, and is used as input and output of multiple methods in different classes. I was able to use:

```
%typemap(jstype) TCustomElementList "long[]"
```

to get the generated Java interface as long[] GetLongs(), but the generated implementation creates new object of type TCustomElementList.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: P.S. Your code isn't quite real - in general it's easier to answer questions if you post a minimal, but complete example of what you're doing - in this instance it too me a minute to spot that everything was private in the two classes you show, as well as missing semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right lines with your typemap, but you need a few more than just that one:

```
%module test

template<class T> class TSizedArray
{
public:
    int GetLength();
    T* GetElements() const;
};

%typemap(jstype) TSizedArray<long> "long[]"
%typemap(jtype) TSizedArray<long> "long[]"
%typemap(javaout) TSizedArray<long> {
    return $jnicall;
  }

%typemap(out) TSizedArray<long> {
  $result = JCALL1(NewLongArray, jenv, $1->GetLength());
  JCALL4(SetLongArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, $1->GetLength(), $1->GetElements());
}

class Producer
{
public:
    TSizedArray<long> GetLongs();
};
```

(This interface ran through SWIG fine, but hasn't been tested further).

You need to set the return types for both the Proxy class and the JNI class (jtype and jstype typemaps). You also need to instruct the proxy to pass through what the JNI code returns (javaout typemap). Then you need provide a bit of JNI glue code that gets inserted to make a new Java array in the C++ side (out typemap).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the incomplete code. 
I was able to build the Swig part, the cross-build had some issues with wrong casts which I hopefully solved. Is it now necessary to make specific typemap for each template expansion (e.g. char *)?
My original question was to include this only as the function output, but I would also need to create type map for function args (in map). And further, Python interface also needs to be available... Any pointers on this? I am completely new to Swig and JNI stuff...

Thanks

Comment: @matej.ko - because you're interacting directly with the runtime of the target language you'll ned to write another typemap for Python. You can use [this technique](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn43) to simplify this slightly. In the Python case it'll just be a single `%typemap(out)` though which builds a `PyList`. In terms of the template issue the easiest way is probably to define a [SWIG macro](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Preprocessor.html#Preprocessor_nn6) that can then be used for each of the template types you care about. The process is roughly symmetric for input.